# how do i remove plusone js from WP?

Tags: wp-query

seems like a simple enough thing to do.....i want to remove it from with dreamweaver but couldnt find it. where is this main articles page??

I also couldnt find where to remove it in appearance in the wp admin areas.

Can someone tell me how to remove this troublesome script from my WP page??

A script with an insecure url of "http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" was loaded on line: 104 of https://www.mydomain.com.au/articles/.

This URL will need to be updated to use a secure URL for your padlock to return.

Answer (score 1):

`http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js` is not a script that a default WordPress install tries to load. It's likely coming from your theme or a plugin that adds social sharing buttons to your site.

Try disabling all plugins to see if the warning still occurs. Then, re-activate each plugin one by one to find the culprit.